# Would someone give me a hint for this problem

Tags: calculus

Find the Taylor expansion around the origin of the function
f
(
x, y, z
) = cos (
xz
−
y
^2
) up
to including terms of
O
(
x
2
+
y
2
+
z
2
)
^4)

. What order are the first neglected terms?
My question is:
The question ask us to find the term up including O(x^2+y^2+z^2)^4, is that means we gonna find the eighth derivative for that since we can not directly put the formula in Cosine series because it has chain rule. What order are the first neglected terms? I serach on the website that it is the error term, I want to know the order is represent taylor expansion order or something else?

Comment: The question ask us to find the term up including O(x^2+y^2+z^2)^4, is that means we gonna find the eighth derivative for that since we can not directly put the formula in Cosine series because it has chain rule.

What order are the first neglected terms? I serach on the website that it is the error term, I want to know the order is represent taylor expansion order or something else?